# Unable to insert a zulu date into mysql database using flask_mysqldb

Tags: python, flask-mysql

When I run the following iwth the value of Job_date being  "2023-01-02T21:00:00.504Z"

```
@api.route('/addjob', methods=["POST"])
def addjob():
   f = open('addjob.txt','w')
   f.write(str(request.json))
   cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
   
   sql = '''INSERT into jobs (job_date,cust_auto_id,cost,paid,mileage,job_desc,person_id) values (str_to_date(%s,"%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%i:%%sZ"),%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''
   try:
       cursor.execute(sql,(request.json.get("jobdate", None),request.json.get("whichauto", None),request.json.get("jobcost", None),request.json.get("paystatus", None),request.json.get("mileage", None),request.json.get("jobdesc", None),request.json.get("whichperson", None)))
       mysql.connection.commit()
   except Exception as e:
       f.write(str(e))
   
   return jsonify([])
```

I get

```
"Incorrect datetime value: '2023-01-02T21:00:00.504Z' for function str_to_date
```

Comment: Right after the table name you only put the list of columns.  Expressions belong in the values part, so put a str to date there.  But your parameter replacement in your client is using % as a special character, you will need to figure out how to get the literal % chars needed in the format string past that

Comment: @ysth updated the code above....

Answer (score 0):

In mysql 8, you can specify an %f format to accept up to 6 digits of partial second:

```
str_to_date(%s,"%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%i:%%s.%%fZ")
```

In earlier versions or mariadb, you can simply remove the Z instead of using str_to_date:

```
replace(%s,"Z","")
```